# Finding shortest distance in km between ZIP code and nearest point at coast of Baltic Sea

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, zip-codes

I am trying to calculate the distance in km between a starting point in form of a ZIP code/ postal code (all located in Germany) and the nearest point at the coast line at both North Sea and the Baltic Sea respectively.

Gladly not only the distance as the crow flies, but also the actual
distance to be driven on the shortest way by car on street in km. I would like to do this for
about 2.000 different postal codes. The postal codes are in an Excel document (.csv) at the moment.

Unfortunately, I have very limited knowledge of Geographical Information Systems.

How can I accomplish this in the easiest way possible?

I am not even sure if I need GIS for this at all or whether there is possibly another way (for example with OpenStreetMap or something similar)?

Comment: So you want to do routing?

Comment: Put in simple terms, probably yes. I want to determine the road distance in km between a starting point which is given (PLZ/ZIP code) and a hitherto unknown point of arrival which needs to fullfill two conditions a) it needs to be at the coast line and b) it needs to be the closest point reachable by car. I want to do this for the Baltic Sea shore line and the North Sea Shoreline. All the starting points are located in Germany though.

Comment: What research have you done on routing/wayfinding? What data did you procure?

Comment: I have no prior experience in routing/wayfinding.

Comment: Use QGIS with QNEAT3 plugin: https://root676.github.io/index.html - see e.g. this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/403386/88814 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/419029/88814