# Average walking distance

Tags: qgis, distance, network

I have OSM network (or city created network, either will work just fine), then I have point layers that corresponds to buildings (or rather entrances) with the number of inhabitants and lastly a point layer with bus stops. How do I find the average walking distance to the nearest bus stop?

> Infrastructure - polyline layer
>
> Buildings - point layer (weighted)
>
> BUS stops - point layer
>
> AVERAGE WALKING DISTANCE TO NEAREST BUS STOP

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### The solution: `OD Matrix analysis`

You can do that with OD Matrix analysis ([see here for the concept](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/od-cost-matrix.htm)). This can be done in QGIS using the plugin [QNEAT3](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QNEAT3/).

1. Once installed the plugin, use `OD Matrix from Layers as Table (m:n)` ([see documentation](https://root676.github.io/OdMatrixAlgs.html)) with the buildings as `From-Point Layer` and the bus stops as `To-Point-Layer`. You get a table with the distance (along the network) from each building to each bus stop.
2. Now you just have to select the shortest distance per building. Use [select by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-expression) with this expression: `minimum(  "total_cost" , "origin_id") = total_cost`, then `Invert selection` and delete all selected features. You're left with one entry per building (`origin_id`) with the minimum distance to the nearest bus stop (`total_cost`) - see below what the different kind of costs mean that the plugin generates.

   *Buildings (blue), bus stops (red); red dotted line: connection from each building to the nearest bus stop **along the network** (not beeline distance): building no 4 is closer to stop no. 2, but along the network, still stop no. 3 is closer. In yellow: network path for all buildings nearest to bus stops no. 1 and 3:*
   [image]
3. To get a weighted output: [Join](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#joins-properties) the `Output OD Matrix` to the initial building layer. Then multiply inhabitants with total costs, sum it up for all features. Then divide it by the total number of inhabitants to get the average distance each individual has to the next bus stop. Use [field calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator), to speed it up, run it just for one selected feature - otherwise the same calculation will be repeated for each feature separately. The expression looks like:

   `sum (inhabitants * od_total_cost) / sum (inhabitants)`

---

### Reduce computation for larger datasets

This tool can become very intensive to calculate for larger layers as it calculates the network distance from each point of the `from` layer to each point of the `to` layer. Often, depending on what your goal is, you don't want to calculate **all**, but just a few connections. Unfortunately, there is no setting for this ([see this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/419134/88814)).

What you can do: split up computation. The trick is to reduce the features used for calculation: select a few origin points and then check the box next to `Selected features only` in the OD Matrix dialog window for the `From-Point_layer`.

Likewise, you could also select only destination points within a certain radius (beeline) from the (selected) start points - adjust the distance that for sure the nearest bus-stop (over the network) is included.

When done, select another set of points etc.

---

### Different types of cost with OD Matrix

Be aware: [OD Matrix](https://root676.github.io/OdMatrixAlgs.html) creates different cost-outuputs: entry, network, exit and total cost:

- **Entry cost**: shortest distance from the the origin point to the network layer (0 if the point is on the network)
- **Exit cost**: shortest distance from the the destination point to the network layer (0 if the point is on the network)
- **Network cost**: the distance along the network
- **Total cost**: entry cost + exit cost + network cost

Comment: Indeed: the average part of the question was not so clear to me, what exactly OP wants to realize - especially as the question states the *weighted* distance (based on number of inhabitants?): what exactly does it mean? Still, I guess this is the easiest part, a simple calculation. The core of the question seems to be finding the smallest distance from each building to the nearest bus stop.

Comment: So, I added an average weight part to the solution - hopefully I understood this correct.

Comment: Yes I saw the *weighted* part, yes, the OP is not clear on this part. And your "favorite QGIS expression" is about "I'm especially fond of the powerful QGIS Expression Engine" :)

Comment: This is brilliantly explained, thank you. I seem to hit a computing wall though. My QGIS stops responding and I dont know if waiting will help. With the solution provided, there is almost 600,000 lines of OD matrixes to filter out. Is there a way to help my computer? Perhaps a way to filter this, using less computational power? Or should I just wait? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know how long it will work - if you're patient, you can run it overnight to see what happens. Otherwise, split up computation. The trick is to reduce the features used for calculation: select a few origin points and then check the box next to `Selected features only` in the `OD Matrix` dialog window for the `From-Point_layer`. Likewise, you could also select only destination points within a certain radius (beeline) from the start points with a distance that for sure the nearest bus-stop (over the network) is included. Then repeat that.

Comment: You could start with just a few points selected to see how long it runs and then succesively increase the number of points to run the `OD Matrix` to find an optimal number of points.

Comment: Oh, I see, you already have the `OD Matrix`, but filtering the feature with the minimum distance is slow. You could filter the table before selecting. Like just start with the first 10 Buildings, like `origin_id` from 1 to 10, then select and repeat that for the rest of the features. Not very elegant, however. Maybe writing a python skript could speed up things. But is is definitely another question and should be asked separately.

Comment: See also here: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/origin_destination_matrix.html

Comment: Actually, I let it calculate over night and there is progress. Ill let you know, when am finished. Thank you.

Comment: Alright, it worked! Thank you very much for your guide as well as for the linked guide, that should be useful information. NOW, is there a way to create polygons that are aligned to one another to show the areas of residents belonging to a particular stop? To show the service area of a particular stop? Thank you.

Comment: Ah, you want to show service areas? You could have done this directly, without creating an `OD Matrix`. Use QNEAT3's `Iso Areas as Polygons` tool.

Comment: Babel, I cannot thank you enough for your insight and help. Really appreciated. Enjoy the holidays.

Comment: Actually, the QNEAT's Service Area or Iso-Area as Polygon (from layer) is not what I am looking for. This joins the overlapping distances. What I am looking for is a boarder when one service area ends and another begins. So that is is easy to see, what bus stop is the closest for a given building. Basically this division (https://imgur.com/a/9EiEQQj) but with polygons. Can you help?

Comment: Sorry, can't see your image. Maybe you post a new question, explaining more in detail what you want to achieve? I can't imagine...

Comment: No need, I figured it out. With my points of buildings, all I needed to do is join with the filtered and cleared out table and then use Concave hull (k-nearest neighbour). This helped me to realise I was using the wrong layer the whole time for my bus stops. But the new link is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QJ8iEnDeThp_atgV47LdwulAkDrgrOm3/view?usp=sharing

Comment: However, now I am hitting some errors. Can you help?

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Stehno/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QNEAT3\algs\OdMatrixFromLayersAsTable.py", line 224, in processAlgorithm
to_coord_list = getListOfPoints(to_points)

...

File "C:/Users/Stehno/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QNEAT3\Qneat3Utilities.py", line 94, in <listcomp>
return [f.geometry().asPoint() for f in qgsfeatureiterator]
ValueError: Null geometry cannot be converted to a point.

Execution failed after 0.24 seconds

Comment: I think this should be better asked as a new quesiton as comments should not be used for extended discussions - you can link to this question, however.

Comment: I did just that and got help. Thank you.