# QGIS OD matrix with option to chose maximum number of destinations and max. distance

Tags: qgis, network-analyst, distance-matrix

Using [QNEAT3 plugin](https://root676.github.io/index.html) in QGIS, you can create [OD Matrix from Layers](https://root676.github.io/OdMatrixAlgs.html). The ArcGIS documentation about [OD cost matrix analysis](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/od-cost-matrix.htm) mentions a `TargetDestinationCount` as well as a `Cutoff_[Impedance]` setting to limit the calculation: for each point from origin layer only get the N nearest points on the destination layer and limit how far out the OD cost matrix will search for destinations. This would be very handy in [cases like this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/419029/88814).

These two options seem not to be implemented in QNEAT3. The GRASS tool `v.net.distance` calculates just the shortest path, but has no options to chose, either, and does not implement `OD Matrices`.

Is there a way in QGIS to create an `OD matrix` with the option to chose a maximum number of destinations and a maximum distance?