# Error when calculating an OD Matrix using QGIS QNEAT?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, error, distance-matrix

I was using QNEAT plugin for QGIS just fine after some very thoughtful recommendation [on this web](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/419026/average-walking-distance#419029). The first time all went well, but I needed to redo it. Now when I try it I get an error.

I can use any QNEAT process and the same error occurs:

```
 Algorithm 'OD Matrix from Layers as Table (m:n)' starting… Input
 parameters: { 'DEFAULT_DIRECTION' : 2, 'DEFAULT_SPEED' : 4,
 'DIRECTION_FIELD' : '', 'ENTRY_COST_CALCULATION_METHOD' : 0,
 'FROM_ID_FIELD' : 'fid', 'FROM_POINT_LAYER' :
 'D:/_PRÁCE/_Trebic/SUMP/_ZPRACOVÁNÍ/QGIS/_TŘEBÍČ - hlavní Q
 GIS/Zástavba/Osídlenost 2020 Třebíč/Osídlenost 2020 Třebíč.shp',
 'INPUT' : 'D:/_PRÁCE/_Trebic/SUMP/_ZPRACOVÁNÍ/QGIS/_TŘEBÍČ - hlavní Q
 GIS/Infrastruktura/Highway Okres Třebíč
 EPSG-5221.gpkg|layername=Highway Okres Třebíč EPSG-5221', 'OUTPUT' :
 'D:/_PRÁCE/_Trebic/SUMP/_ZPRACOVÁNÍ/QGIS/_TŘEBÍČ - hlavní Q
 GIS/Docházka/QNEAT/qneat odm m2n 001.shp', 'SPEED_FIELD' : '',
 'STRATEGY' : 0, 'TOLERANCE' : 0, 'TO_ID_FIELD' : 'fid',
 'TO_POINT_LAYER' : 'D:/_PRÁCE/_Trebic/SUMP/_ZPRACOVÁNÍ/QGIS/_TŘEBÍČ -
 hlavní Q GIS/VHD/highway bus stop Třebíč (5221).shp', 'VALUE_BACKWARD'
 : '', 'VALUE_BOTH' : '', 'VALUE_FORWARD' : '' }
 
 [QNEAT3Algorithm] This is a QNEAT3 Algorithm: 'OD Matrix from Layers
 as Table (m:n)' Traceback (most recent call last): File
 "C:/Users/Stehno/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QNEAT3\algs\OdMatrixFromLayersAsTable.py",
 line 224, in processAlgorithm to_coord_list =
 getListOfPoints(to_points) File
 "C:/Users/Stehno/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QNEAT3\Qneat3Utilities.py",
 line 94, in getListOfPoints return [f.geometry().asPoint() for f in
 qgsfeatureiterator] File
 "C:/Users/Stehno/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QNEAT3\Qneat3Utilities.py",
 line 94, in <listcomp return [f.geometry().asPoint() for f in
 qgsfeatureiterator] ValueError: Null geometry cannot be converted to a
 point.
 
 Execution failed after 0.22 seconds
 
 Loading resulting layers Algorithm 'OD Matrix from Layers as Table
 (m:n)' finished
```

I am trying to do `OD Matrix from layer as lines m:n`.

All layers are the same as before when it worked. I have no idea what changed. I didnt do anything different.

Initially I followed advice in an answer provided for my previous question here:
[Average walking distance](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/419026/average-walking-distance#419029)

Comment: You appear to have a null geometry in one of your inputs, you can use the QGIS tool `check validity` to verify which records these are and remove them/fix them

Comment: Thanks to you I just now realised that removing points with the Vertex Tool doesn't actually remove the point, only its geometry. Did not know that. It would seem I have done something in-between I forgot about. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User 15Step was right. I had some NULL geometries in my bus stops, because I tried to delete some and lazy me used Vertex Tool that only removes the geometry not the feature itself. I had to delete the points completely.