# QGIS QNEAT distance matrix - wrong outputs

Tags: qgis, network, distance-matrix, infrastructure

### The data and the problem

I started to use QNEAT in QGIS (after very helpful advice from user [Babel](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/88814/babel), here: [Average walking distance](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/419026/average-walking-distance)). But when I was trying to pull some nice maps out of it, I noticed the outputs do not make sense.

I was doing the average walking distance from residential buildings to bus stops. The output was in lines for me and I only left the filtered out data with only the shortest distance for each building. You can see that in figure 1 below:

[image: Fig. 1: Lines from buildings to bus stops, red are over 7 mints walking distance]
***Fig. 1: Lines from buildings to bus stops, red are over 7 mints walking distance***

Also can be shown as points in figure 2:

[image: Fig. 2: Points of buildings coloured base on the distance (over 7 minutes are red, under 7 minuter are green and smaller]
***Fig. 2: Points of buildings coloured base on the distance (over 7 minutes are red, under 7 minuter are green and smaller***

Most of the time, everything seems alright, but when you zoom in on one particular area (figure 3 below), then you see something off. Points that are closer to the bus stops then some others have higher total cost of walking distance (see some lines or points that are marked green - meaning they are closer than 7 minutes, and then some marked red, that means they are further than 7 minutes). This should not be happening, as they are closer.

[image: Fig. 3: Zoomed in area with wrong outputs]
***Fig. 3: Zoomed in area with wrong outputs***

There is possibly more errors there, but right now, we can only see it with the scope of under or over 7 minutes. Although, with a quick check of distance (viasually), the rest of the points seem ok, but might not be. See figure 4 below:

[image: Fig. 4: Distance visualised as gradient]
***Fig. 4: Distance visualised as gradient***

---

### The test

I have also taken the liberty of checking the QNEAT output against air distance (which might be completely irrelevant due to the infrastructure influencing the distance in a desired way). I estimated, that if I put network distance against air distance, nothing should be below the red line (you can see one pint there in figure 5 on purpose - red), because that would mean there is a shorter path on a network then through direct line - that would be an error. And whatever data will create a cluster too far off the diagonal line should indicate wrongly selected network (yellow with blue border). See figure 5 below for the purpose of explaining this test:

[image: Fig. 5: Test data to check correlation]
***Fig. 5: Test data to check correlation***

Now the actual data in figure 6:

[image]

***Fig. 6: Data correlation***

I don't know if this tells me something, but to me this seems a little off. Surely, there are others ways and tools to prove if it works.

---

Is it possible that QNEAT always assigns the closes infrastructure and then assumes there is no closer way?

Because this does not make sense all the time, since most block buildings in that area have two entry points and either can be used etc.

Is there a way to make it more precise?

Comment: Figure 3 looks OK. Regarding the red points connected to the central bus stop, we can see that they are closer to the street north of them, and this street is a dead-end on its south-east end, so someone would have to walk the street to its north-west end, then turn left twice and walk back to the south-east to the bus stop. Maybe you would have to adjust the network for pedestrians, so even if 2 streets do not intersects one can still walk through

Comment: Is the network dataset that you are using topologically 100% correct? If some edges are not connected properly QNEAT3 will route using the faulty street network. This could result in the 'errors' you see.

Comment: This is a raw export from OSM. Is there any way to automatically make it better? Or do I have to manually connect everything? Is there a way to make QGIS chose different network even if the dead end is closer?

Comment: I would advise to just check the intersections/crossings or connection of edges near the points where you suspect faulty results. This should lower the burden of a manual check significantly.